# Get push notification event on background mode

Tags: ionic-framework

I am gonna get push notification event on background mode but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
Is it really possible to get notification event on background mode when I work with ionic?
Here are some code snippets of my project.

```
    const options: any = {
        android: {
            senderID: '1066246698789'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: 'true',
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false',
            clearBadge: true
        },
        windows: {},
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        }
    };

    this.pushObject = this.push.init(options);

    // console.log('helper ', nav);
    this.pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
        alert(notification);
        // console.log(notification);

        this.badge.increase(1);
        if (nav) {
            // console.log("this.nav is not null");
            this.processNotification(notification, nav, this)
        }
        else {
            // console.log("this.nav is null");
        }
    });
```

Currently when the app is in background mode, this.pushObject.on('notification') is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

First the JSON you send from FCM will need to include "content-available": "1". This will tell the push plugin to call your on('notification') event handler no matter what other data is in the push notification.

[Background Notifications](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#background-notifications)